# Inside a "for" loop, how can I increment another variable every time the indexer counts "x"units?

Tags: c, for-loop, pseudocode

Title says it all,
i think there is no need for the code as the problem is finding the algorithm itself.

Comment: Your title does not in fact say it all.  It's pretty vague.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: search for modulus (`%`)

Comment: I have a for loop counting to 1200, i want that everytime it counts 40 units it add 1 to another variable j

Answer (score 5):

```
int x=10; //Just suppose
int b=0;
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
 if(i%x == 0){
    b++;
  }
  // Rest of loop code
}
```

That should about do it, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
  if(i%x==0)
  {
     counter++;
  }
  /* Loop Body */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an integer variable `x`, the expression `x % y == 0` will be 1 if `x` is evenly divisible by `y` and 0 otherwise.

```
for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
    counter += (i % interval == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one maybe?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int multiple = 40;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
    {
        if (i % multiple == 0)
            j++;
    }

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, multiple, j);

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it and running it I get the following:

```
$ gcc test.c 
$ ./a.out 
1200, 40, 30
$
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i=0;

while(1)

{

i=(i+1)%x ;

if(i==0)
    counter++;

}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, which was pretty specific about being in a for loop

Comment: This is a Completely Useless Answer. (Edit: It's hardly an answer at all...)

Comment: I answered thinking that OP just needed the logic.My bad didnt see the word "For" .

Answer (score -1):

```
for( int i=0; i < 1200 ;i++)
{
j += i/40;
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. `j` will be 0 for the first 40 iterations, then increment by one for each of the next 40, then by two for each of the next 40, until by 29 for the last 40, ending up at **17400**. Sorry, try again.